# Using CURL to use json's GET using PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am very new to PHP and have done some research on how to call the json's GET function using CURL but there is something I am not doing correctly. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction. I hope I can communicate it properly. Thanks.

In my browser, when I type:
https://myWebSite.com/api/v1/people/26.json?
my browser returns a person with the ID of 26 and all their fields associated with them.

I am now trying to do this call in a PHP file. This is what I have:

```
//jSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = 'https://myWebSite.com';

$username = 'myUsername';  // authentication
$password = 'myPassword';  // authentication

// jSON String for request
$json_string = '/api/v1/people/26.json';

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password,   // authentication
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string
print $result;

?>
```

Comment: Are you having a particular issue with this?

Comment: Without digging into it anymore it appears that it should work. What issue are you running into?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact error is because I do not have access to the API's error logs.

Comment: I changed the code to not include the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS since I am "getting" not "posting".  I changed the url to:  $json_url = 'https://myWebSite.com/api/v1/people/26.json';  and I am finally getting a response. But unfortunately it's:  {"error":""}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your option list:

```
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST'
```

**Edit:** After re-reading the OP, it looks like there was a misunderstanding about what the request should be.  If it is a GET request to a URL, it is more likely that it was supposed to go like this:

```
$json_string = '/api/v1/people/26.json';
$json_url = "https://myWebSite.com{$json_string}";

$username = 'myUsername';  // authentication
$password = 'myPassword';  // authentication

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password,   // authentication
);
```

Comment: Should it be 'POST' or 'GET'?

Comment: If you have to pass some data in the body of the request, which you are doing with `$json_string`, then the request has to be POST.

Comment: What is `$json_string` supposed to be?  Is it supposed to be part of the URL, or is it supposed to be part of the request body?

Comment: I guess I'm not passing any data. Should I remove the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string? And maybe set the url to be:$json_url = 'https://myWebSite.com/api/v1/people/26.json?';

Comment: At first I wasn't sure what the $json_string was supposed to hold. I initially had it set to: $json_string='GET /api/v1/people/26.json' but that didn't work either. From what you're saying, though, it seems that the json_string is for posting data, not getting it, which is what I'm doing. I just need to get it and parse it.

Comment: I've updated the answer to assume a GET request using the $json_string variable as part of the URL.  This is speculative, since I don't really know enough about what you're trying do.  But it makes a little more sense given the little data we have.